Automated Dog Treat Feeder
I’m working on designing an automatic dog treat feeder for people in wheelchairs who have limited mobility.
The need behind this project is that many people who rely on service dogs would love to be able to give them treats for doing a good job at their various tasks, but they are physically unable to do so due to range of motion issues.
I want to design a device that can deliver a single treat with the press of a button or appropriate voice command.
Some of the design requirements are as follows:

cheap to produce (ie <$100 NZD)
minimal footprint (< 150mm square)
works with a variety of different shaped and sized treats
can run off a basic micro controller e.g. Arduino nano or pi zero
single motor is ideal to minimise cost
Easy to use

I think the most difficult part about this project is designing a solution that works with multiple different types of treats due to the irregularities in shape and size.
Most pre existing devices that do a similar thing such as candy dispensers are designed specifically to feed one type reliably.
One idea I had for getting around this issue is having a treat storage container in the form of a circular array of tubes, and a selector disc attached to a small stepper motor which has a singe hole equal to the diameter of the tubes. There is a starting position where the hole in the selector disc is aligned with the section of the container that has no tube. Each tube is then filled with a treat, this could be any treat as long as it fits into the tube.
The micro controller is programmed such that the selector disc rotates to the next tube upon command and when the hole in the disc aligns with a tube, gravity causes the treat to drop out into a bowl for the dog. (Please see attached photos for a basic mockup of the idea)
Although I like the simplicity of this design, the big issue with it is that you can only dispense as many treats as there are tubes before needing to refill which is impractical considering I can only fit 11 tubes of 20mm diameter into what I consider to be a reasonable overall diameter of 130mm.
I don’t mind increasing the hight while keeping the same footprint so I have thought about ways to stack multiple sets of tubes on top of each other with their selector discs offset so that when a bottom tube becomes available the treat above drops into it, but this creates many problems of its own. If they are all driven off a single motor which I’d like for cost saving reasons, then there could be a shaft running though the center connecting all selector discs, but then you’d have the problem of how to refill the whole device once it runs out. You can’t just put the treats in through the top like you could with a single set of tubes because the set above would be blocking the top. Yes, it would be possible to make them all removable but then you have to introduce more complex gearing as you can no longer have a central shaft. This would make the design much more flimsy and difficult to use.
My current thought is whether there as another way of arranging tubes and corresponding selector disc holes in a more efficient way so that I can fit more tubes in the same footprint. Maybe some kind of spiral pattern instead of having them round the outside and wasted space in the middle?
I would love some help with this, all thoughts and alternative ideas welcome.
Cheers,
Billy


Been done, see Back to the Future.

existing cat feeders don't work?

@ratchetfreak I looked into cat/dog feeder options and two problems came up. Either too expensive considering the additional modification required, or only able to work will one size of food. Dog treats come in all shapes and sizes

I agree that handling different shapes of treats is a difficult design task. That consideration is possibly based on the assumption that the customer currently has a preferred treat in mind, and that you can't change that decision.  However it's possible that a customer would want to use your product enough that whatever treat it works with might be acceptable.
I would suggest that, instead, you target a "rev 1" or "minimum viable product" that only handles one specific treat size and type.  For example, choose a popular treat that is made by a large and reputable manufacturer, that has not changed their treat size/shape for a decade, and possibly has different flavors that are all the same size+shape.  (One example)
This will allow you to focus on solving the other problems and get something to customers, allowing you to test the other parts of the idea. (ie. that is the point of an MVP.) For example, the assumption that 11 2cm tubes is not enough - it might be enough! But you may have to get one to a customer to find out.
Also, this handles the <150mm part as well, since handling different sizes might mean handling large dog treats.  You can choose a treat type that is small enough to meet this constraint.
